# Visual Studio 2022 ignores selected framework context for .NET MAUI

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2022, maui, maui-ios

I'm trying to add platform-specific code for iOS to my .NET MAUI app.

I'm targeting an iPhone with `net6.0-ios`:

[image]

However, Visual Studio thinks I'm targeting Android:

[image]

Compiling and running the app works fine (breakpoints within iOS preprocessor directive are hit), but it's a hassle to have to implement the iOS-specific code outside of the conditional preprocessor directives (with a bunch of warnings saying types aren't available) to be able to get some IntelliSense.

<strike>I'm suspecting this is a bug, but curious if there's any workaround?</strike>

Edit: Not a bug, I was just being an idiot not realizing the code editor and debugging target don't necessarily have to be one and the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look in the first picture you posted, at upper left corner. `...App (net6.0-android)`. That is current value of a dropdown, that determines which project Intellisense uses. Change that to iOS.

Comment: Holy smokes, I didn't even notice! I was so focused on `net6.0-ios` being selected as the target framework for debugging. I feel like an absolute tool. Thank you!

Comment: I didn't notice that dropdown too, I've been conditioned to ignore the dropdowns there.

Comment: Good Grief.  Hidden in plain sight.  I got suckered too...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I would literally have never found this.